# What Irish music is similar to Ed Sheeran's "Nancy Mulligan"

Tags: similar-artists, identify-this-genre

My love for the Irish culture, music, dances and everything has been developing ever since last year. I listen to plain music, no words and they're usually full of energy.

However, I just youtube Irish music and that's it. Lately, I came across Ed Sheeran's album "Divide" and it has this song [*Nancy Mulligan*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFlZXlfda6Y) and I definitely want to hear more of this type.

So what's the genre and if any, recommendations of similar artists or albums.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like a english/irish folk rock, one song that sounds similar to "Nancy Mulligan" is the song [*Blackleg Miner*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiC3k8xQdhQ). Richard Thompson does a great rendition of it, just increase the speed to 1.25x to get the same tempo.

Comment: could you add some youtube links for the Richard Thompson version and any others of note ? will make the answer more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick listen to the song you mentioned. I am not a particular fan of Ed Sheeran, but the following might help:

I would suggest you listen to Planxty. I think they would be considered one of the best traditional Irish groups. I would suggest *The Planxty Collection*. You could also try some Christy Moore. Christy played in Planxty, and went solo when they slpit up (they split up a few times, but you get the idea). For me, you can't beat *Live At The Point*.

I would also suggest you try stuff by The Dubliners. I would suggest *The Very Best of The Dubliners*.

From there, you could listen to The Pogues. *Rum Sodomy and the Lash* is good, as is *Hells Ditch*. But you won't go wrong by listening to a Best of, or Collections type of album.

I would also suggest listening to the Dropkick Murphys (*Do or Die* or *Sing Loud, Sing Proud!*, or Flogging Molly (*Drunken Lullabies*). These two groups and mostly American, but with a very Irish influence. They have a more punk element in them too.

Hope this helps,
Seán

Comment: Listening to this makes me want to say: "Slainte !"

Answer (score 1):

I think Great Big Sea has a lot of similar music. If you're from Canada you've probably heard of them. Wikipedia classifies them as folk rock. They're from Newfoundland, which has a lot of Irish and Scottish ancestry.

I don't think any of their vocalists could rival Ed's voice, but they have quite a variety of music. Here are some of their songs I'd recommend:

- Barque In The Harbour (a little slower)
- General Taylor (another slower one, almost purely vocal)
- Ferryland Sealer
- Scolding Wife (humorous)
- Mai-Mac (very fast/high energy)

Answer (score 1):

The music from "Nancy Mulligan" is actually the song "Star of The County Down", performed below by the Chieftains. The music is similar and probably comes from "Dives and Lazarus", an old English Folk Ballad. If you follow the link below it will guide you to more similar music.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GbdB7PlGtc

Answer (score 0):

I actually love Flogging Molly which has some real upbeat vibes and strong passion. Always puts me in such a great mood. Highly recommend!